# Destruction order of the main thread and the use of pthread_key_create

Tags: c++, static, pthreads, destruction, pthread-key-create

I was wondering about the use of `pthread_key_create` while passing in a destructor function.

I wanted to have something like this:

```
static ComplexObject foo;

void workoncomplex(void *) {
    foo.dosomestuff();
}

static pthread_key_t pthreadkey;

void function_called_by_threads() {
    pthread_key_create(&pthreadkey, workoncomplex)
}
```

Obviously I've left out a fair amount of detail.

For any thread that isn't the main thread, this is obviously fine (provided locking etc.), and whenever a thread dies, my `workoncomplex` function gets called and manipulates the `foo` object.

My question is, is this valid for the main thread, as obviously the `pthreadkey`'s calling of the destructor happens at thread wind down, but is it guaranteed to run before the statics are destructed? If so, would I have to check if I'm in the main thread and just return immediately? Or can I just treat all threads the same and assume my static objects will still be around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The destructor function is not called on application exit. It is only called when a thread exits.

If you exit the main thread with `pthread_exit()` then the destructor function will be called, but the application is not yet being shut down so it is safe to use the `static` variables.

If you call `exit()` or return from `main()` then the destructor function will not be called, so the fact that the `static` variables are destroyed is not a problem. Use `atexit()` to ensure that your destructor function is called on return from `main()` or on a call of `exit()`.

Comment: Thanks. Out of interest where did you learn/read this: "The destructor function is not called on application exit. It is only called when a thread exits."

Comment: The POSIX specs and the linux man pages give hints (e.g. `pthread_exit()` is described to call the destructor functions, and this is called implicitly when a thread other than `main()` returns from its thread function). Plus, what I have written matches my experience of using POSIX TLS destructor functions on Linux, Solaris and MacOSX.